# Sum specific columns for selected rows with a specific value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sum a list of columns (colart2015) for specific rows. I can't figure out   what is wrong with my code:

```
# first Select the columns that I want to sum
colart2015 = ['Column1', 
              'Column6',
              'Column10']

# then apply I select the row for the column 'Year' that match the value '2015' and sum the list of columns 'colart2015'

df_pivotms['totalart'] = df_pivotms.loc[df_pivotms['Year'] =='2015'], [colart2015].sum(axis =1)
```

I have got the following error:

`'list' object has no attribute 'sum'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `[]` mismatch, use:

```
df_pivotms['totalart'] = df_pivotms.loc[df_pivotms['Year']=='2015', colart2015].sum(axis=1)
```

If year is integer:

```
df_pivotms['totalart'] = df_pivotms.loc[df_pivotms['Year']==2015, colart2015].sum(axis=1)
```